# Creating/Copying arrays of a generic type

Tags: java, arrays, generics

I've to solve a problem regarding generics which gives me quite the stomache ache.

Basically it's supposed to be an implementation for an array-based max-heap and I have to follow the given conditions.
The code to start from looks like this:

```
//Interface with methods such as insert(), remove(), etc
public interface IMaxHeap<T extends Comparable<T>> {
   ...
}

public class MaxHeap<T extends Comparable<T>> implements IMaxHeap<T>{
    T[] m_array;

    ...

    public MaxHeap(int size){
        //TODO:
        //m_array = new T[size];
    }
    public MaxHeap(T[] array){
        //TODO:
        //Deep copy of array into m_array
    }
}
```

The code for the two constructors is what I'm strugling with.
I am not supposed to modify the signature of the methods so I can't do things like this:

```
public MaxHeap(Class<T> clazz, int size){
    m_array = (T[]) Array.newInstance(clazz, size);
}
```

Additionally, doing the "unsafe" type-casting of an Object[] array like this gives me a runtime excetion (InvocationTargetException)

```
public MaxHeap(Class<T> clazz, int size){
    m_array = (T[]) new Object[size];
}
```

I've found a generic way to make a copy of my array, however it's not a deep copy:

```
public MaxHeap(T[] array){
    m_array = Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length);
}
```

So that this point m_array[0] == array[0] which isn't what I'm looking for.

I'm also not supposed to add other constraints to the class (so no `T exdends Cloneable` either). Given these problems I haven't actually found a way to instantiate my arrays.

I'm somewhat new to generics (I've only been working with C++ templates) so those quirks with T are pretty annoying.
Can you guys point me to a solution that works?

Comment: I fail to see what you mean by "deep copying" an array?

Comment: @fge - A shallow copy would create a new array but place references to the same objects into it. Which means `a[0] == b[0]` holds. A deep copy would clone each objects so that `a[0] != b[0]` but `a[0].compareTo(b[0]) == 0`.

Comment: Ah, I see. You can use `.clone()` then.

Comment: @fge - that's not possible, because clone() is protected and would have to be overwritten for T.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my experience, the standard thing to do is to make the backing array be of type `Object[]`, then cast to type `T` when reading its elements.

Generally speaking, working with generic-typed arrays in Java is really dangerous and confusing. It's best to avoid it as much as possible.

But as you insist on doing things this way, this seems to be the solution:

```
    public MaxHeap(int size){
        m_array = (T[])new Comparable[size];
    }
    public MaxHeap(T[] array){
        this(array.length);
        System.arraycopy(array, 0, m_array, 0, array.length);
    }
```

Comment: Although they haven't explicitly said that I am to use `T[]` instead of `Object[]`, it's hinted at in the exercise. So I'd like to try and use it.

Comment: @s3rius if it's homework, you should tag it as so ;) Also, do you _have_ to use arrays? Can't you use, say, ArrayLists?

Comment: @fge  - I'll retag it. Unfortunately I have to use a normal array.

Comment: @Nayuki - That'd leave the problem that `array` is not a deep copy. But it's at least a step in the right direction!

Comment: How much of a deep copy do you need?

Comment: @NayukiMinase - only one level. So I need clones of the objects directly referenced in the array.

Comment: Try replacing the `arraycopy()` call with this: `for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) m_array[i] = array[i].clone();`

Answer (score -1):

Even with Java generics and type erasure, as your class `implements IMaxHeap<T>`, you *can* get `T.class` at runtime using reflection, and at that point everything becomes easier. The following should work:

1. Call [`Class.getGenericInterfaces()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getGenericInterfaces%28%29) to get the interfaces implemented by your class, with generic type information. The first result should be a [`Type`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Type.html) instance representing `IMaxHeap<T>`.
2. Cast that to a [`ParameterizedType`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/ParameterizedType.html).
3. Call [`ParameterizedType.getActualTypeArguments()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/ParameterizedType.html#getActualTypeArguments%28%29) on that. You will get a `Type` representing `T`.
4. Cast that to `Class<T>`.

Basically, in Java you cannot get the actual type arguments for a given generic class, but you *can* get the actual type arguments for its superclass and interfaces. The thing is that for those cases the runtime needs to know those actual types so it can make the appropiate runtime checks / casts.

Comment: In general, the `Type` instance need not be a `Class`. In fact, it will be a `TypeVariable` unless a subclass of `MaxHeap` is used. Undoing erasure is more complex than that (and not always possible without the caller thoughtfully providing the relevant class object).